# hotstandby postgresql server having passwords of master server

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, postgresql-11

1. Master server : A postgresql user by name 'test' is there with password 'mytest-password-formaster'
2. Slave server : A postgresql user by name 'test' is there with password 'mytest-password-forslave'

Now, i have created HA setup as follows:

1. Modified postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf on master required to act as 'master'
2. on slave server: Cleaned up data_dir, modified postgresql.conf, took data_dir backup from master using "pg_basebackup", and created reconvery.conf to start the postgresql in hotstandby mode.

Now, above steps works fine and my HA setup is also working. Now when i promote the slave server using 'pg_promote', it makes postgresql write enabled. Now the password for 'test' user is of master. i.e 'mytest-password-formaster'.

what i want is, when i promote standby node using 'pg_promote', it should have old password for its user i.e 'mytest-password-forslave'.

How to achieve this ? It is happening as i cleaned up data_dir on slave when setting standby configuration ?

Comment: pg_basebackup replaces everything - so your slave becomes exact copy of master including users and their passwords

Comment: Is there way to handle it then ?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to change password after you make slave database writable by running pg_promote.

Comment: Yes, that i can surely do :) I was looking for any readymade available setting.

Comment: Well, you know point of promoting replica as new master usually is to have everything the same way as it was on old master :-) so change does not cause errors in your app. If you need some different setting then you have to explicitly make that change.